# nano 3.2 always compiles without nls

Tags: zsh, nano, macos-mojave

I'm running macOS 10.14 and zsh.

I noticed that nano 2.0 is installed by default and is missing some features. So, I tried to compile and install the latest version (3.2).

This work fine, except for 2 things:
 - it always compiles without nls .
 - it always compiles without utf-8 support.

```
nano --version
GNU nano, version 3.2
(C) 1999-2011, 2013-2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
(C) 2014-2018 the contributors to nano
Email: nano@nano-editor.org Web: https://nano-editor.org/
Compiled options: --disable-libmagic --disable-nls --disable-utf8
```

During the configure it did gave a warning about utf-8 so it does make sense that is disables utf-8 support.

```
configure: WARNING:
*** Insufficient UTF-8 support was detected in your curses and/or C
*** libraries.  If you want UTF-8 support, please verify that your slang
*** was built with UTF-8 support or your curses was built with wide
*** character support, and that your C library was built with wide
*** character support.
```

What is the proper way to fix this? I would really like the nls support to work.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem and [this Japanese article](https://watchcontents.com/mac-nano-version-update/) helped me.

Although I couldn't understand anything I at least was able to follow the steps needed. Basically, you are missing a library called ncurses. So, before compiling nano you should install it:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/ncurses/ncurses-6.0.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ncurses-6.0.tar.gz
cd ./ncurses-6.0
./configure --with-shared --enable-widec
make
make install
```

and afterwards you configure and install nano as before:

```
cd ../nano-3.2
./configure --enable-all --enable-utf8
make
make install
```

Comment: Thnx for the reply. I'll try tomorrow and see if it works.

Comment: Just tried, didn't seem to work.